# Why won't Travis CI run the CodeClimate script for my Node app?

Tags: travis-ci, code-climate

I have followed the instructions to add CodeClimate to my `.travis.yml` file:

```yml
language: node_js
script:
  - gulp
  - npm test
after_script:
  - codeclimate < coverage/**/lcov.info
addons:
  code_climate:
    repo_token: [ my token ]
```

Everything in my build runs without error, except the `codeclimate` script at the end:

```
[0K$ codeclimate < coverage/**/lcov.info
/home/travis/build.sh: line 41: codeclimate: command not found
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working by installing CodeClimate locally:

```
npm install --save-dev codeclimate-test-reporter
```

I guess Travis CI's Code Climate addon isn't working, or I'm just not specifying it correctly.

Answer (score 6):

I added my `CODECLIMATE_REPO_TOKEN` to my `Travis-CI > Settings > Environment Variables` and removed it from my `.travis.yml` file.

I don't want it installing if the build failed (for performance), so I only install it on success in my `.travis.yml` file, like so:

```
after_success:
  - npm install codeclimate-test-reporter
  - codeclimate-test-reporter < coverage/lcov.info
```

I think the `codeclimate-test-reporter` binary was renamed from `codeclimate` to `codeclimate-test-reporter` and perhaps Travis-CI didn't notice the change yet. This must be why it's broken all of the sudden (I had the same issue).